# En vb.net como puedo subri un dataTable que traigo de excel a sqlite de manera eficiente, son mas de 7000 registros

Tags: vb.net, excel, sqlite

En vb.net como puedo subri un dataTable que traigo de excel a sqlite de manera eficiente, son mas de 7000 registros, si lo hago por for next se demora mucho asi la conexion se realizce una sola vez

Algien sabe una manera en la que pueda enviar la dataTable completa que venga desde la conexion oledb que tengo con excel?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y si nos mostras como haces, a ver si podemos ayudarte?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza un Json, convierte la datatable en un Json, y envialo como un paquete que debe resolver un servicio en el servidor, en mi caso el software estaba en vb .net y el servicio estaba en php, la base de datos era MySql. se logro cargar en tres segundos 12000 registros, cada uno con tres campos, solo era texto